# How to put ListView above two RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, orientation, android-relativelayout

How can I put the ListView above (z-index) these two RelativeLayouts as in the image?

```
<ListView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="150dp"></ListView>
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"></RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"></RelativeLayout>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhVub.png]

Comment: You need a parent layout

Comment: can you explain , which parent?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you actually tested that?

Comment: work thx. Is there exist some different way for this problem?

Comment: NO. I replied the first comment. but I dot know other way.

Comment: This is not the best code. Your `LinearLayout` here doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: i found solution and it's not this. I gave parent RelativeLayout to these two Relative and it work :)